# Synax for functions other than vertex|fragment|kernel in metal shader file

Tags: ios, gpgpu, metal

I'm porting some basic OpenCL code to a Metal compute shader. Get stuck pretty early when attempting to convert the miscellaneous helper functions. For example, including something like the following function in a `.metal` file Xcode (7.1) gives me a "No previous prototype for function" warning

```
float maxComponent(float4 a) {
    return fmax(a.x, fmax(a.y, fmax(a.z, a.w)));
}
```

What's the 'metal' way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three ways I know of:

*(I rewrote the function to be an overload, and to be more readable to me.)*

Actually declare the prototype:

```
float fmax(float4 float4);
float fmax(float4 float4) {
   return fmax(
      fmax(float4[0], float4[1]),
      fmax(float4[2], float4[3])
   );
}
```

Scope it to a file with static:

```
static float fmax(float4 float4) {
   return fmax(
      fmax(float4[0], float4[1]),
      fmax(float4[2], float4[3])
   );
}
```

Wrap it in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
   float fmax(float4 float4) {
      return metal::fmax(
         metal::fmax(float4[0], float4[1]),
         metal::fmax(float4[2], float4[3])
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Approaches 2 (static) and 3 (namespace) worked for me, but for some reason approach 1 (prototype) gives me a `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin/metallib failed with exit code 11` error. Anyhow, you've definitely helped. Thanks